# Use of Facebook metrics

Tags: php, facebook

I have got the user access code as well as the page access with permissions manage_pages and read_insights

$accessToken stores the access token

How can I use metrics like : page_impressions or page_impressions_unique

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/{object-id}/insights/{metric-name}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

but what is the $session variable here and how should I print the result

Answer (score 0):

Here $session variable mean FacebookApp object

```
$session = new FacebookApp('{app-id}', '{app-secret}');
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, '{access-token}', 'GET', '/{object-id}/insights/{metric-name}');
```

Or you can try this

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('my-app-id', 'my-app-secret');

$session = new FacebookSession('my-access-token');

$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts?fields=name,id');
```